# Passing variable from Ruby to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I'm working on sms-validation function onto Sinatra site. And I got this code:

```
post '/coop/sendcode' do
  @code = Random.rand(1000..9999).to_s
  phone = params[:phone].to_s
  HTTParty.get('http://sms.ru/sms/send?api_id=' + api_id + '&to=' + phone + '&text=' + @code)
end
```

And this view:

```
%form
  %div.form-group
    %label Phone
    %input#phone.form-control{:name => "phone", :placeholder => "7 950 123 45 67"}
  %button#sendsms.btn.btn-default{"data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#myModal"} Send
```

And this JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendsms").click(function(){
      var phone = $("#phone").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/coop/sendcode",
        data: {"phone": phone},
        type: "post"
      });
    });
    $("#checkcode").click(function(){
      var serversCode = @code
      var usersCode = $("#code").val();
      if (serversCode == usersCode) {
        console.log("good: srv - " + serversCode + ", usr - " + usersCode);
      } else {
        console.log("bad: srv - " + serversCode + ", usr - " + usersCode);
      }
    });
  });
```

After user types phone number, he press on *Send* button, which opens modal window (with *button#checkcode*) where he can type a validation code from sms. But this code doesn't work, and main question is how to pass *@code* variable from Ruby to JS?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this gem: https://github.com/gazay/gon-sinatra

It will allow you to set the code in the controller like this:

```rb
gon.code = @code
```

and access it in the javascript in a similar way:

```
var serversCode = gon.code
```